# Japanese CSV to JSON parse Error

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I want to parse my CSV file into a JSON file. I have parsed it but it's not getting Japanese characters.

I am using Papa Parser to parse CSV to JSON.

Here is my Code:-

```
Papa.parse("http://localhost:3000/readdata.csv", {
    download: true,
    header: true, 
    worker: true,
    encoding: 'Shift-JIS',
      console.log(row);
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

answer:-

```
{��s����: "0", ��s��(��): "�����", ��s��(����): "���{��s", �x�X����: "79", �x�X��(��): "���-", …}
```

parsing works but not working encoding.

Is there any other solution to parse Japanese CSV (huge file) to JSON?

Comment: Is the encoding of the file correct – it is Shift JIS? (If the file is UTF-8, then it needs to be read that way, for example.)

Comment: @ThomasEdwards yes
it worked fine but getting some error in response
{��s����: "0", ��s��(��): "�����", ��s��(����): "���{��s", �x�X����: "79", �x�X��(��): "���-", …}

Comment: Can you give an example line from the CSV, and what `row` prints in the log?

Comment: Yes I have updated my question sir please check question sir...

if there is another solution then please let me know

Comment: We need to see the CSV too to understand. If possible could you upload the CSV somewhere so we can download it? You only need to include a few lines of it.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards wait sir... i will send you in few minutes

Comment: http://mayursarang.com/PD/readdata.csv you can find data in csv here

Comment: That file appeared to have been encoded in Windows 1252, not Shift JIS. If I do a lookup I get `charset=unknown-8bit`. Check how that file is being saved.

Comment: so you mean to say that need to change encoding:'Windows 1252'..will solve my problem?

Comment: That CSV either has no set encoding, so it’s defaulting to Western default for me, or it is set to that. If you’ve exported it from Excel, that’s probably what has happened. You could try exporting as UTF-8 for safety. If I convert `‹âsº°ÄÞ` using `windows-1252/latin1` into bytes, I get `8B E2 8D 73 BA B0 C4 DE`, which when converted to shift jis becomes `銀行ｺｰﾄﾞ` – which is ‘bank code’?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards, No Sir If i upload file then it works perfectly...but when i am trying remote file..it is not working

Comment: Is there any other solution for remote file parse ??

Comment: You need to be sure that it’s sending it to you correctly, it is likely the server causing the problem, not Papa. If you do `curl -i http://localhost:3000/readdata.csv` in the command line, what is the `Content-Type`?

Comment: Maybe fetching the file via `XMLHttpRequest` and forcing the encoding is the best way. I tried setting the `Content-Type` to use Shift-JIS, but I'd get garbled text anyway.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Thanks Sir I really appreciate your efforts Sir thanx :-)... and for Content-Type i got "text/csv"

Comment: No encoding type after it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't really modify the relevant parts of your code, but seems to work for me. Firefox 58 here.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="papaparse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function openFile(event) {
        var input = event.target;
        Papa.parse(input.files[0], {
            download: true,
            header: true, 
            worker: true,
            encoding: 'Shift-JIS',
            complete: function(results) {
                console.log("All done!", results.data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me when I retrieved the file from a URL, even if I set the web servers headers to:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=shift_jis
```

or

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=shift-jis
```

**Update**: Actually, this appears to work just fine. You may run into problems if you've got an old version in the browser cache however.

Here's a demo: https://blog.qiqitori.com/stackexchange/papaparse/papaparse-sjis-from-url.html

```
$ curl -I https://blog.qiqitori.com/stackexchange/papaparse/readdata-charset-sjis.csv
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Mar 2018 05:23:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Mar 2018 15:48:17 GMT
ETag: "15a-567ee1ea9847f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 346
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=shift_jis
```

If you cannot change your server settings, here's a work-around that will allow you to do this without changing the server settings at all: I suggest using `XMLHttpRequest` to load the CSV into a variable, and forcing the encoding to `Shift-JIS`.

```
function load(url, callback) {
    var Xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (Xhr.readyState === 4 && Xhr.status === 200)
            callback(Xhr.responseText);
    };
    Xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    Xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=Shift_JIS');
    Xhr.send();
}

load("http://.../readdata.csv", function (contents) {
        Papa.parse(contents, {
//          download: true,
            header: true, 
            worker: true,
//          encoding: 'Shift-JIS',
            complete: function(results) {
                console.log("All done!", results.data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, directly linking to papaparse.com's `papaparse.js` didn't appear to work, so I removed the link.

Comment: thank you sneep san ...You are very genius san..This answer helped me 
a lot thanx :-)

Comment: I actually updated it a second ago. Turns out that it does work when you modify the server's headers, but you may run into caching problems. Papa Parse currently doesn't appear to allow you to override the MIME type, but maybe it would make sense to add this feature sometime in the future.

Comment: Ok so can you please tell me, what is solution for that?

Comment: I'd suggest just using the second code snippet I pasted. The one with the `load()` function. Sorry if I'm being confusing.

Comment: this helped me a lot... doumo arigatou gozaimasu :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167316/discussion-between-parth-raval-and-sneep).